# Visual Studio 2012 Stale DLL

Tags: visual-studio, dll, deployment, visual-studio-2012, installshield

### Intro

I don't know if this is a bug or there is something I'm completely missing.

I have a Project (Windows Service), let's called it WINSERV. And I have 3 DLL's which it depends which come from 3 seperate Projects (Project A, B, C). However A has a dependency on C. And B has a dependency on A and C.

When Building Installer with InstallShield LE, for some reason my Project C is always a STALE version which I cannot get to change. I increment the version, "make clean && rebuild", and the installation (on a remote server) always includes the STALE version.

I set each project that has a dependency on C, to not "Copy to Local", so allowing Project WinServ to maintain the "reference" itself, and copy it across for the Installer.

### Problem

But again, no matter what I do, when I install it's the stale version. After a few hours, I did manage to get around the problem, by removing "Copy to Local" on Project WINSERV, and adding in Project C as an addition to Application Data (Project C's Primary Output) to the InstallShield Install Project. This seems to work!!!!

### Question

I did try "MAKE CLEAN" a thousand times. I checked Project C DLL version before building and creating the Installer and it was always STALE, old version.

Anyone can explain this? or Bug?

PS. InstallShield LE does not do Windows Services so if you reading this, don't get caught out.

Comment: Having same issue.  The strange thing is that the version of the stale dll installshield is including in the output doesn't existing anywhere on my PC (searched my.dll from PC root). Burned many hours troubleshooting so far.  Really wish MS left the VS installer in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a bug in Visual Studio 2012.
I've managed to replicate in the following fashion:

While having a Project opened (referencing let's say MYSQL 5.1.4).
I then commence to uninstall the MySQL Connector and install 5.1.7.
I close Visual Studio 2012 and recompile and all works well.

However when I build with InstallShield it still references 5.1.4 despite it being uninstalled. My thoughts is that it's caching it somewhere and accessing it later during the build process.

How I solved it, is after installing a newer/older/different version of an existing DLL, I then REBOOT my machine and all is now well.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a similar problem I had.

For some reason InstallShield sometimes gets DLLs from the temporary ASP.NET folder (even if your project is not ASP)

Try clearing the folder: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files